# How to map a list to a DTO where one property is a string and the other property is my source list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following:

```
class Product
{
  int Id;
  string Name;
}

class ProductDTO
{
  int Id;
  string Val;
}

class LookupDTO
{
  string Name;
  IEnumerable<ProductDTO> options;
}
```

I have a list of `Product` and I need to map this into the `LookupDTO` where `Name = "myList"` and `options = myProducts`

```
var myProducts = new List<Product>();
myProducts (new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" });
myProducts (new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Banana" });
myProducts (new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Pear" });
```

I want to map this into `LookupDTO` to produce the following:

```
LookupDTO
  Name: "myList"
  options: [ { id:1, val:"1 - Apple" }, { id:2, val:"2 - Banana" }, { id:3, val:"3 - Pear" } }
```

How can I map what I have into this form?

Answer (score 0):

I would split this up and not do it in one super map.

First, add the mapper configuration between `Product` and `ProductDTO`:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // whatever other configurations you may have
    cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>().ForMember(
        product => product.Val,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(dto => dto.Name));
});
```

Then, map that property with the mapper:

```
var result = new LookupDTO()
{
    Name = "myList",
    options = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>>(myProducts)
};
```